# (Scale) Zoom into a UIView at a point

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, quartz-graphics, cgaffinetransform

Something I don't understand about transformations. I want to zoom in to say the top right corner of a UIView (the main view). I use `CGAffineTransformScale` and have tried both setting the center/anchorPoint as well as `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` to no avail.

I can't figure out how to set the translation properly so that it will zoom in on this point.

```
CGAffineTransform tr = CGAffineTransformScale(self.view.transform, 2, 2);

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
            self.view.transform = tr;
            self.view.center = CGPointMake(480,0);

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

Comment: What about zooming to arbitrary points? For instance in response to a user tapping the screen?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are setting the center of the view to the top right corner. That means you're zooming in on somewhere to the lower left of the center.

Try this

```
CGAffineTransform tr = CGAffineTransformScale(self.view.transform, 2, 2);
CGFloat h = self.view.frame.size.height;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
    self.view.transform = tr;
    self.view.center = CGPointMake(0,h);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

This will set the center of the blown-up view to the left bottom corner, effectively zooming in with the top right corner fixed.

This code doesn't have the height hardcoded, which is a little more portable (to an iPad of iPhone 5).

You need to first save `h` before setting the `transform` property, because after that you should not rely on the value of `frame`.

**edit**

To make it work for any scale `s`, use this:

```
CGFloat s = 3;
CGAffineTransform tr = CGAffineTransformScale(self.view.transform, s, s);
CGFloat h = self.view.frame.size.height;
CGFloat w = self.view.frame.size.width;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
    self.view.transform = tr;
    self.view.center = CGPointMake(w-w*s/2,h*s/2);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

To make it work for bottom left, use this:

```
CGFloat s = 3;
CGAffineTransform tr = CGAffineTransformScale(self.view.transform, s, s);
CGFloat h = self.view.frame.size.height;
CGFloat w = self.view.frame.size.width;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
    self.view.transform = tr;
    self.view.center = CGPointMake(w*s/2,h-h*s/2);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

To make it work for bottom right, use this:

```
CGFloat s = 3;
CGAffineTransform tr = CGAffineTransformScale(self.view.transform, s, s);
CGFloat h = self.view.frame.size.height;
CGFloat w = self.view.frame.size.width;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
    self.view.transform = tr;
    self.view.center = CGPointMake(w-w*s/2,h-h*s/2);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

**See also: [How to scale (zoom) a UIView to a given CGPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329286/scale-zoom-uiview-to-given-cgpoint/18397535)**

Comment: Thanks, this works as is for me, but makes it zoom in more towards the actual center on scales above 3. How would this work, say for bottom  right? Oddly enough, this works for me : self.view.center = CGPointMake(-280,-h)

Comment: That correct, since the center of the blown up view depends on the scale. I added examples for bottom right/left and for any scale. Just remember: first you blow up the view (making it 320*s,480*s big), and then you are setting the center of that view.

Comment: Brilliant! That's the simple little algorithm I was missing, thank you. Would MakeTranslate be a better option than setting the center, if I want to easily revert?

Comment: This is wonderful little piece of code. You should blog it ;)

Comment: This might be out of the scope of the question, but how would you modify this to scale to any arbitrary CGPoint in a view?

Comment: Works great.  In the completion I end up with adding `self.view.transform = .identity` to recover distorted few subviews.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is still interested, here is the Swift 3.0 solution, to which I added the possibility to fade out correctly.

(I know there are two enums missing, but the code is still readable and I think you will get the concept)

```
func animateZoom(direction: ZoomDirection, type: ZoomType, duration: Double = 0.3, scale: CGFloat = 1.4) {
    var cx, cy: CGFloat
    var tr: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity

    if (type == .IN) { tr = self.transform.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale) }

    let h: CGFloat = self.frame.size.height;
    let w: CGFloat = self.frame.size.width;

    if (type == .IN) {
        switch direction {
        case .LEFT_DOWN:
            cx = w*scale/2
            cy = h-h*scale/2
            break
        case .LEFT_UP:
            cx = w*scale/2
            cy = h*scale/2
            break
        case .RIGHT_UP:
            cx = w-w*scale/2
            cy = h*scale/2
            break
        case .RIGHT_DOWN:
            cx = w-w*scale/2
            cy = h-h*scale/2
            break
        }
    } else {
        cx = w/scale/2
        cy = h/scale/2
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
        self.transform = tr
        self.center = CGPoint(x: cx, y: cy)
    }, completion: { finish in })
}
```