# Making an animation to expand and shrink an UIView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, caanimation

I want to create an animation that will resize an UIView and its contents by a factor. Basically, I want to make an animation that first expands the view then shrinks it back to the original size.

What is the best way to do this? I tried CALayer.contentScale but it didn't do anything at all.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446899/scale-zoom-into-a-uiview-at-a-point or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329286/how-to-scale-zoom-a-uiview-to-a-given-cgpoint?lq=1?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can nest some animation blocks together like so:

Objective-C:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                 animations:^{
                     yourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                                      animations:^{
                                          yourView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                                          
                                      }];
                 }];
```

Swift 2:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in
    yourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
    }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in
            yourView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        })}
```

Swift 3/4/5:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    yourView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
}) { (finished) in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { 
        yourView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    })
}
```

and replacing the scale values and durations with your own.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a smaller approach that also loops:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^{
                     yourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

The option `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat` is what makes it loop, if you don't want it to keep "breathing".  The animation block acts as the "inhale" and the `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAutoreverse` option automatically plays the "exhale" animation.

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5 UIView extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func pulse(withIntensity intensity: CGFloat, withDuration duration: Double, loop: Bool) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
            loop ? nil : UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(1)
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: intensity, y: intensity)
        }) { (true) in
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    }
}
```

And then use the following:

```
yourView.pulse(withIntensity: 1.2, withDuration: 0.5, loop: true)
```

Just make sure you replace `yourView` with your own view.